# Time fields and calculations- Best Practices

Tags: ios, datetime, core-data, time

I am planning to save and manipulate time information in an iPhone application. Surprisingly I find very little discussion in searches regarding best practices in iOS.
My goal is to easily:
-calculate durations from start, finish, break fields.
-round entries by user selectable default increments (15 min, 30 min, etc.).
-sum, avg and graph the results as desired

My question is, what is the best way to save the time data? Do I save the full dates as NSDate? Do I parse out the time portion only?
Is the CFAbsoluteDate or CFInterval types a better way to go? These are alien to me, but search in Apple reference docs always seem to end up there. Unfortunately I see no example databases cited.

I can envision most of what I intend to do, but hoping for some pointers before I commit to a model one way or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are extremely memory-constrained, NSDate is recommended. It has native time difference functions, which makes calculating time intervals as simple as:

```
NSDate *savedDate = [self getDateSavedFromEarlier]; // retrieve saved date
NSDate *anotherDate = [self getAnotherDateSavedFromEarlier]; // retrieve another saved date
NSTimeInterval interval = [savedDate timeIntervalSinceDate:anotherDate];
```

Comment: so would you recommend saving the entire date/time or just the time itself? Some have suggested using a relative date of 0 or other and I have seen it done that way in VB.

Comment: Just save it all. The size of this data isn't large; just save it.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about your application - I think you should just start with storing `NSDate`s.

You're rounding things up in large increments, so it seems unlikely that you are generating/storing dates at volumes where it's going to make too much difference.

Best practice is to not complicate things, and not optimise before you've profiled the application.